# MySQL only updates a from first row instead of all rows

Tags: mysql

i'm having trouble with a MySQL UPDATE query which isn't doing what i want.

I have 3 tables and they look like this (relevant portion only):

```
[inventory table]
id
population

[item table]
id
populationGeneration

[items_for_inventory table]
id
inventory_id
item_id
amount
```

What i am trying to accomplish is the following.
Inventory has an id and a population count column. The population is a value which needs to be altered and not overwritten.

Item contains a id and a generation count column. This means that for each item with this id, this is the amount of population it generates and should be added to Inventory.population.

Last is a linking table which contains the id of the inventory and the id of the item and last the amount of this item.

**A simple example**
inventory population = **5000**

item 1 populationGeneration = **1**

item 2 populationGeneration = **3**

items_for_inventory links the item to the inventory by id and specifies that the inventory contains for example 20 pieces item 1 and 3 pieces of item 2. so:

items_for_inventory id 1, amount **20**

items_for_inventory id 2, amount **3**

When i run the desired script i want ALL items that contain populationGeneration to be added to the initial population, which means:

inventory population = **5029** (20x1 and 3x3).

The script that i tried that doesn't work (i tried many):

```
UPDATE inventory ivt, 
        (SELECT 
            tmp.inventory_id, 
            tmp.amount * tmp.populationGeneration AS population
            FROM (SELECT ifi.id AS ifi_id, 
                inventory_id,
                item_id, 
                amount, 
                populationGeneration 
                FROM items_for_inventory ifi 
                JOIN item itm ON ifi.item_id = itm.id) tmp
       ) AS tmps
SET ivt.population = tmps.population 
WHERE ivt.id = tmps.inventory_id AND itm.id = tmps.item_id;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you need to aggregate to the inventory level *before* doing the assignment.  When multiple rows match the update, one arbitrary matching row is chosen for the update.  They don't accumulate.

Fortunately, this is easily fixed:

```
UPDATE inventory ivt JOIN
        (SELECT ifi.inventory_id,
                sum(ifi.amount * itm.populationGeneration) AS population
            FROM items_for_inventory ifi JOIN
                 item itm
                 ON ifi.item_id = itm.id
            GROUP BY ifi.inventory_id
       ) newp
       ON ivt.id = newp.inventory_id
    SET ivt.population = newp.population ;
```

Comment: You are fantastic! fixed it after changing the 'tmp' aliasses ;-) thanks man!